# Python script completed, but is not setting poetry environment variables

Tags: python, python-poetry, python-3.10

Hello I am trying to run the following python script against an already initialized virtual environment:

```
import subprocess

# List of Poetry commands to be executed
poetry_commands = [
    "poetry install",
    "export PARAM_1=<value>",
    "export PARAM_2=<value>",
    .
    .
    "export PARAM_N=<value>",
    "poetry run start"
]
# Iterate over each Poetry command and execute it
for command in poetry_commands:
    try:
        # Run the command in the shell, wait for it to finish
        subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Command '{command}' failed with error code {e.returncode}")
```

For some reason the script completes, however the `poetry run start` command fails due to export params not being applied. How can I assure that the export env variables are correctly set after `poetry install`?

Answer (score 1):

You are running each command in its own separate shell.

Each shell is created, running an export statement and then destroyed,

To correctly pass environment variables, pass `env` to [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please elaborate a bit more, do you mean pass the virtual environment like this in the subprocess params: env={"PATH": "<path>"}

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish and why, so I cannot help you more. [Please see how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to workaround the problem by using `os.environ` to set the env variables:

```
import subprocess
import os

poetry_commands = [
    "poetry install",
    "poetry run start"
]

# Set environment variables using os.environ
os.environ["PARAM_1"] = "<value_1>"
os.environ["PARAM_2"] = "<value_2>"

for command in poetry_commands:
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Command '{command}' failed with error code {e.returncode}")
```